# How to concatenate paths with wildcard character in cross-platform safe way?

Tags: powershell

I would like to concatenate two directories and an asterisk "*", for use in the `Copy-Item` cmdlet.
Currently I have something like the following

```
$fooDir = "foo"
$barDir = "bar"
$srcDir = Join-Path -Path $fooDir -ChildPath $barDir
$srcFiles = Join-Path -Path $srcDir -ChildPath "*"

$destDir = "buzz"
Copy-Item -Path "$srcFiles" -Destination $destDir -Recurse
```

Can I reduce the two `Join-Path` lines in some way that is just as cross-platform safe?
Or better yet, can I tell the `Copy-Item` Cmdlet that I want the directory's files copied without needing the asterisk ?

The `Join-Path $fooDir $basrDir "*"` syntax doesn't seem to work with the asterisk.

Comment: Just found `-AdditionalChildPath` which allows the following to work: `$srcDir = Join-Path -Path $fooDir -ChildPath $barDir -AdditionalChildPath "*"`. Any other ways?

Comment: The `-Recurse` on `Copy-Item` is already doing that for you, there shouldn't be a need to add `*` on your path.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon without the `\*` that copies the directory as well. In this case I want to copy only the contents, not the directory itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cross-platform script only ever runs in [PowerShell (Core) v6+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) on Windows, you can indeed take advantage of [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path)'s `-AdditionalChildPath` parameter, which, in combination with `-Path`,  you can use *positionally* as follows:

```
$srcFiles = Join-Path $fooDir $barDir *
```

However, you can also take advantage of the fact that PowerShell allows you to use `\` and `/` *interchangeably* as path separators in file-system paths, so using `/` explicitly works on Windows too, even in *Windows PowerShell*:

```
$srcFiles = "$fooDir/$barDir/*"
```

Note that if you want to ensure that *hidden* files and subdirectories are also copied, be sure to also pass the `-Force` parameter to the [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) call.